# How to draw a nvd3 line chart inside an angular directive

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js

How to draw the line chart using nvd3 angular directives.

I've followed this [url](http://newtips.co/st/questions/32474381/dotted-line-in-nvd3-line-chart.html).

To my data,I'm unable to draw a graph.Do I need to change the code over here.

Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue ...

Myscope:

```
 $scope.data = [{
                "x": "2015-10-01",
                "y": "244"
    },
            {
                "x": "2015-07-01",
                "y": "0"
    },
            {
                "x": "2015-06-01",
                "y": "117"
    },
            {
                "x": "2015-05-01",
                "y": "5353"
    },
            {
                "x": "2015-04-01",
                "y": "11159"
    },
            {
                "x": "2015-03-01",
                "y": "7511"
    },
            {
                "x": "2015-02-01",
                "y": "6906"
    },
            {
                "x": "2015-01-01",
                "y": "10816"
    },
            {
                "x": "2014-12-01",
                "y": "3481"
    },
            {
                "x": "2014-11-01",
                "y": "1619"
    },
            {
                "x": "2014-10-01",
                "y": "4084"
    },
            {
                "x": "2014-09-01",
                "y": "1114"
    }];

$scope.options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'lineChart',
            height: 450,
            margin: {
                top: 20,
                right: 20,
                bottom: 40,
                left: 55
            },
            x: function (d) { return d.x; },
            y: function (d) { return d.y; },
            useInteractiveGuideline: true,
            xScale: d3.time.scale(),
            "xAxis": {
             "axisLabel": "Months (ms)"
             },
            "yAxis": {
                "axisLabel": "WW (v)",
                "axisLabelDistance": -10
            }
            xAxis: {
                axisLabel: 'Months',
                ticks: d3.time.months,
                tickFormat: function (d) {                    

                    return d3.time.format('%Y %b')(new Date(d));

                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                axisLabel: 'WW',
                tickFormat: function (d) {


                    if (d == null) {
                        return 0;
                    }

                    return d3.format('.02f')(d);
                },
                axisLabelDistance: 30
            }
        }
    };
```

My html:

```
  <nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the question is not very clear but I’ll try to help you

1. if you want use angular with nd3.js it is more easy find some module than help you to do that like https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3
2. if you know it and only want to create a chart that looks like the link in the question you can use the `angular-nvd3` module (yeah link above)The directive is

   ```
   <nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3>
   ```

You can see this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/lBKFld?p=preview
 It has the chart that you want with angular and nvd3.js you only have to change options and data to fill your needs
(The plunker is from the module) 
I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi friend, the problem is your data, see your link, the dates looks like this: "1409509800000" you have to convert your dates to that format, remember use the {"key": "Line1", "color": "#008000", "values":[HERE PUT YOUR ARRAY XY]} inside $scope.data